# Setting browser/os restrictions on Django

Tags: python, django, security, web

I’m new to django programming, not python, and could do with a hand.

I am attempting to make a website exclusive to a certain device. I have created a disallow page accessible by `'/disallow/'`. How do I go about running os/browser checks that then redirect in the event the os/browser is not on the verified list.

I know the information I am wanting to check will be in the request and I can use
**`request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`**

However where do I write any logic required and how could I apply this to any page the user tries to access.

Any help would really be appreciated
Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want a Django [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/). It sits in front of all response handlers, so it can capture every request and take any action on it that you require.

Simple example (untested), a function that returns a function:

**`your_app/middleware.py`**

```py
def restrict_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        if request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == ...:
            return redirect('/disallow/')
        else:
            return get_response(request)
    return middleware
```

Then register `your_app.middleware.restrict_middleware` in the `MIDDLEWARE` array in your settings file.

Note that such browser/OS detection relies on what the browser/OS itself is claiming that it is, and can easily be spoofed on the client. So don't use this for any security purposes.